# force object files in current directory even when subdir-objects is on

Tags: automake

I have 2 libraries that share same source files:

```
# src/lib_mt/Makefile.am:
libppb_la_SOURCES = rphs_mt.c timer_mt.c

# src/sipplib/Makefile.am:
libsipp_a_SOURCES = ../lib_mt/rphs_mt.c ../lib_mt/timer_mt.c
```

Each source file compiled twice. First for `lib_mt` with `-fPIC`, second for `sipplib` without `-fPIC`.

Object files for each library created in corresponding directory.

Eventually `subdir-objects` becomes default. How to keep current behavior for these 2 source files? Some explicit rule maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable that the moment it becomes the default. What you *can* do instead is migrate this to a non-recursive Automake buildsystem. At that point, it will know that there are different targets compiling the same source files with different flags (it requires `AC_PROG_CC_C_O` to be called in `configure.ac`.)

Alternatively, the hacky version is to create a `src/sipplib/rphs_mt.c` file that only contains

```
#include "../libmt/rphs_mt.c"
```

so that it is actually a separate build target.